# Variable initialization error in a function

Tags: c++, c

This function is implemented inside my program but when it is called there is an error saying that the variable root is used without being initialized, any reason why?

```
int find(int x)
{
    int i, j, root;

    for (i = x; parent[i] != i; i = parent[i])
        root = i;
    /* path compression */
    for (i = x; parent[i] != i; j = parent[i], parent[i] = root, i = j)
    {
        //donothing
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: if the first loop runs zero times, you never assign `root`.

Comment: Just as Barmar states. You should have a default value for root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if `parent[x] == x`? The neither loop will actually run, because the condition `parent[i] != i` will be false (since `i = x`), and therefore `root` will never actually be set to a value.

So, when we return `root`, it's value is undefined, meaning it can be *anything*.

The easiest way is to set `root` to some initial value, say, `0`, before the loops.

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says. If `parent[i] != i` is false at the start, then `root` will be read without being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't be sure that `root` will be initialized because all references to it are inside `for` loops, which may not execute even a single time if the condition is not met.

1. Just set `root=x` when you declare it;
2. Your iterator variable `i` should probably be declared in the `for` loop to properly limit its scope

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are doing

```
for (i = x; parent[i] != i; i = parent[i])
        root = i;
```

so in your code you are telling for i=x and than root=i
or you didn't yet specified what is the value of x ! so how the compiler will know the value of root ?
you should initialize X before using it in the for !